# Automatically load new posts in Wordpress without refreshing page

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, refresh

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to get Wordpress to automatically load new posts on the homepage, rather than having to refresh the page?

I imagine this could be achieved with ajax/jQuery, but have not managed to find any suggestions.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning

You can do something like this:

```
<script>
var i = setInterval( function() {
  $(".posts").load('post.php'); //Whatever the php page to do the query against here
 }, 60000 //timeout in miliseconds
);
</script>
```

If you need to stop the Interval for some reason, use:

```
clearInterval(i)
```